# In Oracle when do I use the keyword ONLY in a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm going through the Oracle certification course and I'm looking at the examples.  The instructor isn't really talking about when to use ONLY and when not to use ONLY.  Is the ONLY keyword used in specific instances and is ONLY semantics or does it do something specific that I missed?

Here's an example

SELECT
product_name,
quantity
FROM
inventories
INNER JOIN products
USING(product_id)
ORDER BY
quantity DESC
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;

Is this required?  If I don't give the ONLY keyword will it make a difference?

Comment: It might help if you posted some examples (you're looking at).

Comment: Or at least which statement/clause you're asking about. The only thing that immediately comes to mind is the [`select ... fetch` clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__BABBADDD), which can be `only` or `with ties`. You might be looking at something else completely though.

Comment: You're correct.  It is for scenario while using FETCH

Comment: Your question says "the keyword ONLY in a query" though. It doesn't mention the [12c row limiting clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```sql
> SELECT product_name, quantity
> FROM   inventories
>        INNER JOIN products USING(product_id)
> ORDER BY quantity DESC
> FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
> ```
>
> Is this required? If I don't give the ONLY keyword will it make a difference?

Lets take a simple example and run it:

```sql
SELECT * FROM DUAL
ORDER BY DUMMY
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ORA-00905: missing keyword
> ```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM DUAL
ORDER BY DUMMY
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Outputs:

> | DUMMY |
> | --- |
> | X |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1e9c22dc2378f2b2ce743d7ac8842075)*

So, yes, a keyword is required; as you can see from the syntax diagram for the [row limiting clause of the `SELECT` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6):

> [image: Syntax diagram for row limiting clause of SELECT statement]

Then you must end the row limiting `FETCH` clause with either `ONLY` or `WITH TIES`.